# Swift, Strings and Memory Addresses

Tags: string, swift, memory-address, value-type

There is something I am not understanding about how Swift manages memory address of `String(s)`

### 1. Reference types

Here `foo` and `boo` are 2 pointers to the **same memory location**.

```
class Foo { }

let foo = Foo()
let boo = foo

unsafeAddressOf(foo) // "UnsafePointer(0x7FCD13719BE0)"
unsafeAddressOf(boo) // "UnsafePointer(0x7FCD13719BE0)"
```

Good.

### 2. Value types

```
let word0 = "hello"
let word1 = word0
```

Now `word0` and `word1` are `value types` but here the `copy on write` mechanism is involved.

> [...] However, Swift only performs an actual copy behind the scenes when it is absolutely necessary to do so. Swift manages all value copying to ensure optimal performance, and you should not avoid assignment to try to preempt this optimization. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-XID_134

So why do they have 2 different memory addresses?

```
unsafeAddressOf(word0) // "UnsafePointer(0x7FCD1342ACE0)"
unsafeAddressOf(word1) // "UnsafePointer(0x7FCD13414260)"
```

### 3. More

Also please note that `String` is a `struct` that [somehow conforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26403542/swift-string-doesnt-conform-to-anyobject) to `AnyObject`.

Tested with Xcode 7 GM Playground and Swift 2.0.

Comment: "So why do they have 2 different memory addresses?" So why do you care?

Comment: String is automatically bridged to NSObject when passed to a function expecting AnyObject, see also my comment to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637688/is-it-possible-to-mutate-a-string-in-swift-such-that-it-can-be-proven-to-modify. Actually I get the same output for word0/1 in a compiled project, but different output in a Playground.

Comment: @matt Ahah...:D Yes. I'm starting to think the same thing. But this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32626383/do-instance-references-really-work-in-swift and the intense exchange of comments below my answer pushed me to ask this question.

Comment: Similar observations here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31298461/a-different-bridging-between-array-and-dictionary. I think that you cannot make any assumption on whether the automatic bridging to a Foundation object returns the same instance each time or not.

Comment: @MartinR: understood. Thank you a lot. If you want to write your comments as an answer consider it accepted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
func unsafeAddressOf(object: AnyObject) -> UnsafePointer<Void>
```

takes an `AnyObject` parameter, i.e. an instance of a *class*.
It returns the pointer to the storage used for the object referenced
by `object`.

`addressOf()` cannot be used with *struct* variables:

```
struct Foo { }
var f = Foo()
let a = unsafeAddressOf(f)
// error: cannot invoke 'unsafeAddressOf' with an argument list of type '(Foo)'
```

`String` is a `struct`, *however*, it is automatically bridged to `NSString` when passed to a function expecting an object. So

```
let word0 = "hello"
let p1 = unsafeAddressOf(word0)
```

actually executes

```
let p1 = unsafeAddressOf(word0 as NSString)
```

You get not the address of the `word0` variable, but the pointer to the
memory location of the bridged `NSString` object.

It seems that you cannot make any assumptions on whether this bridging
returns the identical `NSString` object (or more generally, the same
Foundation object) when done repeatedly on the same Swift string. In a Playground, even

```
let word0 = "hello"
let p1 = unsafeAddressOf(word0)
let p2 = unsafeAddressOf(word0)
let p3 = unsafeAddressOf(word0)
```

returns three different addresses (but the same addresses in a compiled
project). The same observation (for arrays and dictionaries) was made
in [A different bridging between Array and Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31298461/a-different-bridging-between-array-and-dictionary).

Comment: So then how can we apply this to structs? If I want the memory address of a custom struct, the TRUE mem address, zero casting as a foundation class object, what can I do?

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 3.0**
Unmanaged.passUnretained(object).toOpaque()