# Is it OK to use `__FUNCTION__` as key for `objc_getAssociatedObject`

Tags: swift

In Objective-C one can use `_cmd` as key for `objc_getAssociatedObject`, as described in this [NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/). In Swift, only `__FUNCTION__` serves a similar purpose to `_cmd`. But I am not sure whether it is safe to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `objc_getAssociatedObject()` needs a *unique pointer* as key.
In Objective-C, `_cmd` has the type `SEL` which is a pointer, and is
unique according to the referenced article.

In Swift, `__FUNCTION__` has the type `String` which is not a pointer.
When passed to a function expecting a pointer, the string is
*converted* (probably to `NSString` as in [Swift, Strings and Memory Addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32638879/swift-strings-and-memory-addresses)). It is not guaranteed that this
conversion yields the same pointer in each call. Here is a simple
example which demonstrates the problem in a Playground:

```
func bar(ptr : UnsafePointer<Void>) {
    print(ptr)
}

func foo() {
    bar(__FUNCTION__)
    bar(__FUNCTION__)
}

foo()
```

Output:

```
0x00007f8173c06500
0x00007f8173e00020
```

As you can see, the same `__FUNCTION__` is passed as two different
pointers to the `bar()` function.

It *seems* that in a compiled project you'll get the same pointer for
each call, but that is – as far as I know – not documented, and since
it does not work in a Playground I would not rely on it.

Therefore I consider it as *not safe* to use `__FUNCTION__` as
the key for associated objects.

A safe way would be to use the address of a global property
as in [Is there a way to set associated objects in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133058/is-there-a-way-to-set-associated-objects-in-swift).

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to use that as a key, it's just a `String` literal. However, you should try and avoid `objc_getAssociatedObject` and the objective-c runtime in general when using Swift since it's not supported for all types and it goes against the idea of safety in Swift. Hopefully *fingers crossed* we'll see more dynamic introspection capabilities with Swift 3.