# Inout parameters don't have the same address

Tags: ios, swift, pass-by-pointer, inout

I have three classes A, B and C. A has a resource called rA. What I am trying to achieve is that all of those instances have a reference to the exact same resource.

So to concrete in Swift terms:

**Class A has a property called foo:**

```
private var foo : [Bar] = [Bar]() // shared resource
```

**Class B has a property called foo which is passed into the initializer as an inout parameter:**

```
private var foo : [Bar]!
init(inout foo:[Bar]){
    self.foo = foo
}
```

**Class C is analogous to Class B**

How come, if I pass `foo` from Class A to Class B (or C) the address changes ?

In A I would pass it to B (or C) like so:

```
let b = B(foo: &self.foo)
```

When I print the address after initialization of `foo` in A it gives me a different address than after assignment in B.

```
class A{
    private var foo = [Bar]()
    func someFunc(){
        NSLog("\n\n [A] \(unsafeAddressOf(self.foo))\n\n") // different from output in B
        let b = B(foo: &self.foo)

    }
}

class B{
    private var foo: [Bar]!
    init(inout foo: [Bar]){
         self.foo = foo
         NSLog("\n\n [B] \(unsafeAddressOf(self.foo))\n\n")
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this is the case ?

Comment: `unsafeAddressOf()` takes an `AnyObject` parameter, therefore in your case the Swift array with type `[Bar]` is bridged to an `NSArray`. This bridging may or may not result in the same object when done repeatedly.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, that makes sense. Is there any other way I can check if they reference the same object ?

Comment: Note that Swift arrays are *value types* and `self.foo = foo` "copies" the array (even if the actual elements are only copied on demand). – If you need a real *reference* which you can pass around then you can wrap the array in a `class`. Or use `NS(Mutable)Array` but then you lose many Swift features.

Comment: That's why I love you @MartinR. Always tremendously helpful. Pack your comments into an answer and I'll reward you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift arrays are *value types*, therefore in

```
self.foo = foo
```

you assign the *value* of `foo` to `self.foo`. This are two independent arrays now
(even if the actual elements are copied only when one of the arrays is mutated).

Also you cannot take the address of a Swift array with `unsafeAddressOf()` because
that function takes an `AnyObject` parameter which is an instance of a class, i.e.
a *value type*. In

```
 unsafeAddressOf(self.foo)
```

the Swift compiler actually bridges the Swift array to an `NSArray`. As demonstrated
in [Swift, Strings and Memory Addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32638879/swift-strings-and-memory-addresses),
this may or may not result in the same object when done repeatedly. In any case,
the printed address is *not* the storage location of the Swift array.

If you need a real reference which you can pass around then you can wrap the array in a class.
Using `NS(Mutable)Array` might also be an option, but then you lose many Swift features.