# defer in function didn't work in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift-playground

Im testing Swift 2.0 and the new keyword `defer` in a Playground:

```
func branch() -> String {

    var str = ""

    defer { str += "xxx" }
    str += "1"

    let counter = 3;

    if counter > 0 {
        str += "2"
        defer { str += "yyy" }
        str += "3"
    }      
    str += "4"

    return str    
}

let bran = branch()
```

I expected `bran` to be `"123yyy4xxx"`, but it actually is `"123yyy4"`

Why did my defer `(str += "xxx")` not work as expected?

Comment: it works but the `defer` is invoked _after_ the scope runs out, therefore first the `return str` is called then the scope runs out and it calls your `defer` and add the `"xxx"` to the local instance which happens _after_ the value returns.

Answer (score 7):

> A defer statement defers execution until the current scope is exited.

That what apple says. So the defer statement will be executed after return statement. That's why you cannot see the expected result.

Answer (score 7):

Greg is correct and if you want to get same result with your code then you can do it this way:

```
var str = ""

func branch() {

    str = ""
    defer { str += "xxx" }
    str += "1"


    let counter = 3

    if counter > 0 {
        str += "2"
        defer { str += "yyy" }
        str += "3"
    }
    str += "4"

}

branch()
str    //"123yyy4xxx"
```

Comment: Global variables based solutions are almost never good solutions. You also forgot to reset the `str` variable, so calling `branch()` multiple times gives different results.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly: the `defer` gets executed as you can clearly see when adding a `print(str)` to it.

Now to explain why the returned value does not reflect the changed value:
The reason for this is that `String` is immutable - whenever you write `str += something` you create an entirely new `String` instance and store it inside `str`.

If you write `return str` that returns the current instance of `str` which is `123yyy4`. Then the `defer` gets invoked and assigns the completely new and unrelated `String` `123yyy4xxx` to `str`. But that does not change the previous `String` object stored inside `str`, it simply overwrites it and therefore does not affect the `return` which has already "happened".

If you change your method to use `NSMutableString` instead you will always operate on the *same* instance and the result will therefore correctly output `123yyy4xxx`:

```
func branch() -> NSMutableString {
    var str = NSMutableString()
    defer { str.appendString("xxx") }
    str.appendString("1")
    let counter = 3;
    if counter > 0 {
        str.appendString("2")
        defer { str.appendString("yyy") }
        str.appendString("3")
    }
    str.appendString("4")
    return str
}


let bran1 = branch()
```

In that code the return returns the instance stored in `str` and the defer alters that *instance*, it does not assign a new instance but changes the already present one.

For explanation sake you can try to view the memory address of `str` at different stages:

- at the time of the `return`
- before changing `str` in the `defer` block
- after changing it

For the `NSMutableString` all three cases will yield the same memory address meaning that the *instance* stays the same. The `String` one however prints two different memory addresses resulting in the returned String to point to `someAddress` and the deferred one to point to `someOtherAddress`.

Comment: Note that `unsafeAddressOf()` is completely meaningless with a Swift string (or any non-class type), it returns the address of a temporarily bridged NSString: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32638879/swift-strings-and-memory-addresses.

Comment: @MartinR hmm :/ any Idea what I should use instead to visualize the memory change of the String instance?