# How to add vendor/product ID to a USB matching dictionary

Tags: swift, macos, swift3

In Swift 2.2,  I can add the VENDOR and PRODUCT IDs to the usb matching dictionary with `unsafeAddressOf`.

```
var serviceMatchingDictionary = IOServiceMatching(kIOUSBDeviceClassName)

private let VendorID = 0x8564
private let ProductID = 0x5000

let vendorIDString = kUSBVendorID as CFStringRef!
let productIDString = kUSBProductID as CFStringRef!


CFDictionarySetValue(serviceMatchingDictionary, unsafeAddressOf(vendorIDString), unsafeAddressOf(VendorID))
CFDictionarySetValue(serviceMatchingDictionary, unsafeAddressOf(productIDString), unsafeAddressOf(ProductID))
```

In Swift 3, I use [withUnsafePointer(to arg: inout T, _ body: (UnsafePointer) throws -> Result) rethrows -> Result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39123023/5571327).

However, it did not work. It can print out the address, but it crashes when calling `CFDictionarySetValue`

```
withUnsafePointer(to: &VendorID) { vendorIDPtr in
        withUnsafePointer(to: &ProductID, { productIDPtr in
            withUnsafePointer(to: &vendorIDString, { vendorIDStringPtr in
                withUnsafePointer(to: &productIDString, { productIDStringPtr in
                    // Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0)
                    CFDictionarySetValue(matchingDict, vendorIDStringPtr, vendorIDPtr)
                    CFDictionarySetValue(matchingDict, productIDStringPtr, productIDPtr)
                })
            })
        })
    }
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crash in your attempted
Swift 3 code happens because the address of an integer variable is passed to a function which expects the address of a Foundation *object.* But you can completely avoid using `CFDictionarySetValue` and unsafe
pointer manipulations for this task.

`IOServiceMatching()` returns a `CFMutableDictionary` which is toll-free
bridged to `NSMutableDictionary`:

```
let matchingDictionary: NSMutableDictionary = IOServiceMatching(kIOUSBDeviceClassName)
```

Now you can simply add the ids as `NSNumber` objects:

```
let vendorID = 0x8564
let productID = 0x5000

matchingDictionary[kUSBVendorID] = vendorID as NSNumber
matchingDictionary[kUSBProductID] = productID as NSNumber
```