# Array mutability append in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, append

The new array was set up in itself call append()

In Xcode 7.3.1, I get these results:

```
import Foundation

var data = [[10]]
var firstObject = data[0]

print(unsafeAddressOf(firstObject))
firstObject.append(30)
print(unsafeAddressOf(firstObject))
print("--------")
print(firstObject)
print(data)
print("--------")
data[0] = firstObject
print(data)

--output:--

0x000000015fdea8a0
0x000000015fdea930
--------
[10, 30]
[[10]]
--------
[[10, 30]]
```

I try change object in array, but I failed.

so,i need run `data[0] = firstObject` in `array.append()` every time ?

Comment: Why are you printing memory address. you can append data directly by `data[0].append(30)`

Comment: Note that `unsafeAddressOf` is *useless* with value types (such as `firstObject` which is an  `Array`), see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32638879/swift-strings-and-memory-addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code, yes you need.

Swift `Array` is value type unlike Foundation `NSArray` which is reference type.

The line

```
var firstObject = data[0]
```

creates a copy of the object at index 0 of `data` and assigns it to the variable.

The next line

```
firstObject.append(30)
```

appends 30 to `firstObject` but `data` remains unchanged.

To update `data` you need to assign `firstObject` back to index 0 of `data`